# i am trying to to connect my SQL table on my database with express server to send the columns in the response

Tags: sql, express, select, response

so this is my code

```
    const url = `postgres://.......`;
const pg =require (`pg`);

 const client =new pg.Client(url);
```

```
app.get("/data", handeldata)
```

```
    function handeldata(req ,res ){
let sql = 'select * from houses ;'
client.query(sql).then((results)=>{

    
    res.send(results.rows);
}).catch((err)=>{

console.log(err);

})


}
```

there is no error massage only the respone on thunder is reloading or not recived  and i tried to console log inside the function but it did not see it ?

[check my table here  "Select * from houses"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjd2t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create the connection:

```
client.connect(); //<=====

app.get("/data", handledata);

function handledata(req, res) {
  let sql = "select * from houses ;";
  client
    .query(sql)
    .then((results) => {
      res.send(results.rows);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
}
```